# How to make client calls to table controller in azure mobile app

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a table controller using the Entity framework... I don't know how to make calls to it from a Universal Windows app.. This question is about making calls from a client application... not from curl, postman.

```
 public class UserController : TableController<User>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<User>(context, Request);
    }

    // GET tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<User> GetUser(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }

    // PATCH tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<User> PatchUser(string id, Delta<User> patch)
    {
         return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // DELETE tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task DeleteUser(string id)
    {
         return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```

How do I make calls to it from a Windows Universal App?
At least, where can I find that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation is a great place to start: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/

Short version - there is a whole SDK available for use.  If you prefer samples, you can check out my quickstart: https://github.com/adrianhall/quickstarts

Comment: Thank you.. I t worked with the official documentation examples.